What can rejuvenate my saddlebags?
What can rejuvenate my saddlebags?
The fabric is fine but the color has faded due to Texas sunlight and heat.


I’m not an expert on fabrics, color or coatings, but I’d very much assume that it’s permanent damage caused by UV radiation and not something which can be reversed.

While your saddle bag is from a bike, their care is not a subject to this Stack Exchange site. You might get a useful answer on Lifehacks or one of the other sites. https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/

Quite certainly permanent damage but one may be able to stain the bag with some paint (or whatever is the right English term) for fabrics. However, other sites are ondeed better for that.

@VladimirFГероямслава Dye

Fading indicates you ride a lot, fading is a feature.

What sort of fabric? Synthetic fabrics won't dye readily but some are cotton which will

@Vladimir F Героям слава The saddle bags are not permanently damaged other than the sun bleaching out some of the color.

You may get positive results using beeswax to waterproof the fabric.   Test on an inconspicuous surface first.
In short, you apply a light all-over coat of warm wax, perhaps mixed with some light oil and let it soak in then set over a couple days.
The colour should improve but it will never look "new"   The water resistance will improve, but the fabric will also become more stiff, so it can pay to fill the bags with something while the wax sets.
There's also a risk the wax will mark other things that contact the bag, like floors/walls.
If you find the wax's smell unpleasant, then ask a horse-person or motorcyclist what they use on their leathers.  There are a bunch of options, but what works best in Texas may not be the same as other latitudes.

See my comment.

Is beeswax going to be any protection to a nylon cloth (cordura-like)? The fibres will not absorb anything so you'll basically have wax sitting on the surface. Also Texas, hella melty.

@WarrenBurton good points - definitely "try in an inconspicuous area" first.

Like a well-used but cherished knapsack or duffle bag, a saddlebag accumulates dirt. You may not see the dirt quite as well on a black bag as you would on a lighter color, but it is what contributes to its degraded look. If it fits the job and you're happy with its performance, it's a testament to good craft and to a good fabric that it continues to serve its purpose.
You cannot put it in the washing machine, but you can dunk it in a large plastic container filled with water and a little dish soap. Let it sit for a few hours, hose it down with fresh water, and then dunk it again in a container of clean water. The discarded two sets of water will tell you how much dirt you're washing out. Next simply leave it outside to dry (it will likely take a full day).

It is faded from being out in the sun. I see some useful ideas on other answers that I will use. I can simply get some fabric spray of my favorite color. I also have a water-proof spray that I can finalize it with.

I giggled at "leave it overnight in the sun"

@Criggie Lol, well, I'm saturated with drugs to fight a nasty cold. My days and nights are mixed right now.

@fixit7 Oh, I see. You're trying to get it looking new again, and with new coat of color. Good luck with that.

@Sam7919 Thanks for your comment.
